# Reduce two-finger scrolling sensitivity Thinkpad T480s - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, elantech

The Thinkpad T480s comes with the Elantech touchpad driver installed. All of the solutions I have found are predicated on the fact the laptop has a Synaptics driver installed.

Is there a way to configure the Elantech driver?